# Having problems deploying project environments in MobileFirst 7

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I've installed MobileFirst 7 for Eclipse (CN4V3EN) and I'm having problems deploying project environments.

The steps i've taken:

- Created a MobileFirst Project->Hybrid Application and gave it a name.
- Tried to run on Mobile First Development Server and it executed flawlessly.
- Created an iPhone environment Tried to run on Mobile First Development Server and got:

  Failed to deploy application 'werwer' to MobileFirst Server:

> HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> [ERROR   ] An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to
>   the container. [ERROR   ] SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application
>   class
>   'org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest:195'
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
>   org/apache/openjpa/util/com$worklight$common$util$SortedProperties$0$proxy,
>   method: remove signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z)
>   Expecting to find integer on stack    at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:195)
>   at
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
>   at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:43)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1275)
>   at [internal classes] at
>   com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:61)
>   ...

It also happens to projects i've done in Worklight 6.2 (after migration for 7).

I'm using windows 7 and java 1.8.0_31 (64bit).

The same happens if I deploy to a Mobile First 7 Server (CN4V2EN) on OpenSUSE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worklight and MobileFirst Platform do not support Java 8.
Downgrade to either Java 6 or 7 and try again (make sure Eclipse is also configured to use that version JRE).